# is dispatcher a individual process or it just runs in context of some other process

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

hello
in unix BSD 5 operating system,do we have dispatcher a separate process with process id or its code is executed with context of some other process.
for example if we have some user running program which needs to be dispatched back to "ready to run in memory"...so dispatcher would runs in user program context or not?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux (Unix, BSD, MacOS X, ...) kernel acts as 'the dispatcher'.  It decides which process is to run next, adjusting the priorities and status of the processes, and ensures that the process selected does not run for longer than its quantum of time (before the kernel gets to supervise which process executes next once again).  The kernel uses pre-emptive scheduling (rather than cooperative scheduling).  It is categorically not running in the user program context; it runs in the kernel context.

You can debate whether the kernel is a separate process.  It is certainly not a part of your user process, so it is separate; the question is whether it is really a process.  However, that's a somewhat philosophical issue and really doesn't affect you - there is a separate part of the system that controls scheduling and dispatch of processes.